# Xcode 10.0 simulator showing black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 10.0 on macOs 10.13.6, in past several days I am facing issue on xcode simulator that "Simulator shows black screen always" [Even not showing boot screen when device boot or simulator boots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O96CJ.png)

[Xcode still shows Launching, Attaching application to simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xzLx.png)

[Even XCode shows Running of on Device still black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcIZS.png)

Note: It is not issue of lock button simulator tried it also.
Tried multiple solutions including **Simulator > Reset content and setting.** ,
**Delete Derived Data**, **Tested on different simulator of different iOS Versions**, **Checked with multiple Projects**

None of above solved my problem, I can run application on only my personal physical Device, Attached Image on links

Comment: you have not set entry point?

Comment: @SagarBhut If you are talking about Storyboard entry point than its already set, If not please specify

Comment: Issue has been Solved in received new update of xCode 10.1 from Apple.